# Why Spring Boot ignores @Named annotation when deploying a WAR?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I have to deploy a Spring Boot application in a Tomcat 8 as a WAR.

Everything works when launching the application via the embedded Tomcat but when I deploy to a standalone Tomcat, components are wired only if annotated with `@Component` annotation (or one of its derivatives, like `@Service` or `@Controller`). If I use the JSR-330 `@Named` annotation, beans are not found and the container cannot start the application because it cannot find any bean that qualifies for the wiring:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [TestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Not all JSR-330 annotations are ignored, as `@Inject` works.

**Is there a way to configure Spring Boot to honor JSR-330 annotations when running in a standalone (not embedded) container like Tomcat?**

Relevant code sections:
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>art</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

ContextConfiguration (in the root package):

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class ContextConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

}
```

TestService (in the root package)

```
@Named
public class TestService {
}
```

TestRestController (in the root package)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRestController {
    @Autowired
    public TestRestController (TestService testService) {
        super(testService);
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters create a valid `SpringBootServletInitializer` as your current doesn't do anything. You need to tell it what the configuration classes are. Next make sure that the `@Named` is actually available on the server else it will do nothing...

Comment: @M.Deinum From `SpringBootServletInitializer` javadoc (1.3.0-RELEASE): To configure the application either override the configure(SpringApplicationBuilder) method (calling SpringApplicationBuilder.sources(Object...)) or make the initializer itself a @Configuration. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.html

Comment: I have never seen it work without a `configure` method also putting it in the root package is generally a bad idea. As I already mentioned make sure that the server has the `@Named` class/dependency jar, if it isn't available (as by default in tomcat) the annotation is basically useless.

Comment: The @named annotation is in your classpath ?

Comment: It's in the root package just for this example.